# Why is garbage value printing in server code

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I actually tried a client server code using TCP Select. I don't know why is the garbage value printed after every request from the client is printed on the server

Here is the server code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgd87fby6tif9q6/server.c

Here is the client code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlv1im06gfw5i1w/client.c

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a site for code review, but for technical questions and answers, so please pose a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating the message received on the server as a string but aren't sending a nul terminator from the client.  This leads to old content in `recv_buf` and possibly further down the stack being displayed as printf scans memory for the next byte with value 0.  You could address this by either sending a nul terminator from the client by changing you `send` call to include the string terminator in your message

```
send(sockfd, send_buf, strlen(send_buf) + 1, 0);
```

or in the server by adding a nul terminator after receiving the message

```
recv_buf[nbytes_recvd] = '\0';
```

[Original answer retained below in case you also want to remove the newline from messages.  And because that'd have inadvertently fixed your problem.]

"garbage value" doesn't give us a lot to go on...

At a guess, these characters may be newlines (single character with value 0x0D).  From the [fgets man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) (my emphasis)

fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. ***If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer***. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

The string your client reads may end in a newline.  If you don't want to send this to the server, you could remove it by adding

```
size_t len = strlen(send_buf);
if (len > 0 && send_buf[len-1] == '\n') {
    send_buf[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

to your client, between its calls to `fgets` and `send`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jp57eo8ppele91/Screenshot%20at%202012-12-12%2003%3A10%3A26.png                     As you can see in the screen shot after "1234" garbage value is displayed....so I want to remove that garbage value !!!

Comment: @sam_3191 Ok, I see what the problem is now.  I've updated my answer

Comment: @simoc thanks a lot...its running perfectly. I have just one more query. Now I want to send the string that I got back to the client from the server. What should I do in that case !!

Comment: @sam_3191 Glad to help.  Can you post your new query as a new question please?  This site works best with a single question per post.  Also, if you're happy with this as an answer, can you consider accepting it (by selecting the outline of a tick/check mark on the left of my post)